# Read OracleClob with/in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, clob

I want to Read a Oracle Clob with C#. In the Clob are a PDF.

this is my methode:

```
    public static void Sql2Clob(OracleConnection connection, string query)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        Connection = connection
    };

    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();

    OracleClob clob = reader.GetOracleClob(0);
    //OracleBlob clob = reader.GetOracleBlob(0);
    byte[] b = new byte[clob.Length];
    clob.Read(b, 0, (int)clob.Length);

    using (var fs = new FileStream("testfile.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        fs.Write(b, 0, (int)clob.Length);
    }
}
```

If I open the File I get a short String like in SQL-Developer

```
SELECT DATA FROM ARCHIVE.FILES WHERE PARENTID = '123'
```

> archive:Mapping0:247

but a other Tool (non open source), reads exactly from this row a pdf

what is todo, to get the FILE?

thanks